# Mysql date warning data truncated

Tags: mysql, date, format, warnings

I'm having an interesting issue with Mysql DATE format.
I have this table :

```
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| file_path   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_export | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

When i'm updating a row using the date function : NOW(), the date is updated with this format :

```
'2014-01-23'
```

But when i'm using another date format, like hand-written one like :

```
update backup_conf_allied set date_export='2014-23-01' where file_path='IDF-952584-SW1' ;
```

The date_export column transforms into :

```
'0000-00-00'
```

Warning table tells me that :

```
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'date_export' at row 3628 |
```

Why? The date format is the same as NOW() function.
Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Posted query

```
update backup_conf_allied set `date_export='2014-23-01'` where file_path='IDF-952584-SW1' ;
```

What it should be

```
update backup_conf_allied set `date_export='2014-01-23'` where file_path='IDF-952584-SW1' ;
```

MySQL Support DATE format as 'YYYY-MM-DD' , `Year then Month then Date`, So you are updating a Date column with wrong value `"2014-23-01"` , There are only 12 months in year, you are using month 23 which is invalid that's MySQL is converting it to ZERO DATE (0000-00-00)

Comment: NOW() returns current time stamp in correct format as "2014-01-23 15:48:50"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, my issue was that I was trying to upload a datetime object as a date object.  Although that's not the same issue that Gui O was having, if you run into this, make sure that you're actually trying to upload a date object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem but for a different reason. My MySQL column has a `datetime` type, but my datetime values are from Python, and they look like this: `'2021-04-01 03:58:50.088087'.

So the result is to truncate before the period:

```
t = t[0:19]
```

e.g.:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
'2021-04-03T08:28:41.602373'
>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()[0:19]
'2021-04-03T08:28:44'
>>>
```