# Python MySQLdb upload CSV to existing MySQL table; after, Date and Time fields are wrong/truncated

Tags: python, mysql, date, csv

I have an existing table in MySQL, in a table 'art.nettop_masterfile2'. I have run a CSV import from within MySQL Workbench, and it didn't give the date and time fields properly(they were truncated).

```
*LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE    
'C:/Users/ecoker/Documents/webapp_1010/FilesToValidate/FilesAsOf010715/mft4.csv' 
INTO TABLE art.nettop_masterfile2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
ignore 6 ROWS;*
```

I tried using the Python MySQLdb library to populate the same table. The code is as follows.

```
import csv
import MySQLdb
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='****',
    db='art')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/ecoker/Documents/webapp_1010/cyber/dnides/mft4.csv' 
INTO TABLE art.nettop_masterfile2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
ignore 6 ROWS; """
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I am wondering what I need to modify in the above Python script in order to properly populate my date and time fields through Python MySQLdb, so they aren't truncated?? Thanks!!

I'm receiving an error message in the console and it's not populating the table. The error message is 
    '...uploadmft.py:66: Warning: Data truncated for column 'FN_mtime' at row 3
      cursor.execute(query)
    uploadmft.py:66: Warning: Data truncated for column 'FN_adate' at row 3
      cursor.execute(query)
    uploadmft.py:66: Warning: Data truncated for column 'FN_atime' at row 3
      cursor.execute(query)
    uploadmft.py:66: Warning: Data truncated for column 'FN_cdate' at row 3
      cursor.execute(query)
    uploadmft.py:66: Warning: Data truncated for column 'FN_ctime' at row 3
      cursor.execute(query)
    uploadmft.py:66: Warning: Data truncated for column 'FN_bdate' at row 3
      cursor.execute(query)
    uploadmft.py:66: Warning: Data truncated for column 'FN_btime' at row 3
      cursor.execute(query)
    uploadmft.py:66: Warning: Data truncated for column 'shortfilename_mdate' at row 3
      cursor.execute(query)'

I am not sure how to change the query within the .py script to make the MySQLdb properly communicate the CSV and populate these date and time fields correctly, e.g., not show up as mostly 00:00:03 and 0000-00-00, etc..?

The MySQL table has date and time columns in MySQL, when I observe the table, some of which are referenced in the error message.
Here is a snippet of the first few rows of SOME of the date and time fields, as they appear in the .csv.

```
SI mdate     mtime-UTC      SI adate     atime-UTC      SI cdate     ctime-UTC      SI bdate     btime-UTC      FN mdate     mtime-UTC   
3/20/2014    10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786
3/20/2014    10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786         3/20/2014  10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786
3/20/2014    10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786   3/20/2014    10:50:23.786
```

**UPDATE>>>**
I think the best route is to add to my MySQL code...http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

```
*LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE    
'C:/Users/ecoker/Documents/webapp_1010/FilesToValidate/FilesAsOf010715/mft4.csv' 
INTO TABLE art.nettop_masterfile2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
ignore 6 ROWS;*
```

...I need to add SET statement to convert the strings in the CSV to Date or Time, for those variables. The question, is the most efficient way to write this in the query above???
A set statement for all 20some Date and Time variables...Further, since I don't have a Unique Field, and the CSV contains no ID columns, I may have to use MySQLdb for a CREATE Table statement as well? 
The format of the CSV can be seen in the snippet I provided in the original post with Date and Time variables.

***UPDATE***

```
import csv, datetime
csv.register_dialect('pipes', delimiter='|')
newrows=[]
with open('mft01091.csv') as fin:
    rin = csv.reader(fin, dialect='pipes')
    cols = next(rin)
    for row in rin:
        for i, (name, value) in enumerate(zip(cols, row)):
            if value == '':
                value = 'NULL'
            else:
                if 'date' in name and value:
                    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%m/%d/%Y')
                    row[i] = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        newrows.append(row)
```

Comment: I also have realized that this table is a Django Table and it has and ID column in it, which will misalign the import of my CSV, since the CSV file does not have an ID. Further, there is no field unique, that I can assign as PK (default ID in Django)???

Comment: and what's in the rows of your CSV file?  Clearly they're overly long, compared to the MySQL table's schema (which it would also be nice to see!-).  Python is the least of your worries, except that it may be able to write, from your CSV with too-long columns, another CSV with columns properly trimmed so you can `LOAD DATA`.  But, how the trimming shd be done, w/o knowing more about the table schema and the CSV you have, is impossible for us to guess.

Comment: I couldn't attach a snapshot, and the 39 fields were too many to fit, but the fields excerpted above, 'SI mdate', 'mtime-UTC', are the format for the date and times that are truncated. I think I need to use the SET, string to date for MySQL and integrate into Python code? I'd like to add a create table to the embedded code as well....

Comment: Finally the problem shows so I'm following up with an answer.

Comment: Assigning `value = 'NULL'` is totally useless, as it's leaving `row[i]` set to the empty string.  Assign `row[i] = 'NULL'` instead to try to clean up `row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Mysql date warning data truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305092/mysql-date-warning-data-truncated) : **MySQL supports DATE format as 'YYYY-MM-DD' , Year then Month then Date**.

You need to reformat your dates that way (ISO international standard format), where now you seem to have 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

Python can certainly help you do that (copy the input CSV into an output one with dates in the right format which you can then load into MySQL):

```
import csv, datetime

with open('input.csv') as fin, open('output.csv', 'w') as fou:
    rin = csv.reader(fin)
    wou = csv.writer(fou)
    cols = next(rin)
    fou.writerow(cols)
    for row in rin:
        for i, (name, value) in enumerate(zip(cols, row)):
            if 'date' in name:
                d = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%m/%d/%Y')
                row[i] = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        fou.writerow(row)
```

I imagine the problem with times is similar but I have not investigated it in similar detail; I can't immediately spot your problem there as I easily could w/the formatting of dates.

Incidentally, you'll need to pass delimiters &c to the `csv.reader` and writer constructors if they're not standard (vertical bars for example aren't:-).

Comment: What if I want to not output to another file, because it's large. Can I append to a dict or list, or manipulate the reader object? THanks

Comment: If it's too large to output to a file it's surely **WAY** too large to keep in memory.  Apart from that, sure, you can avoid having `fou`, remove the statements where it occurs,, have a `newrows=[]` before the `with`, and `newrows.append(row)` in place of `fou.writerow(row)`.  Or, just send the data to MySQL for insertion at that time, singly or in bunches.  As for "manipulating the reader object", I have no idea what you mean or what good you think it would do to you.  My specific solution assumed you still wanted to `LOAD DATA`, just **good** data:-)

Comment: code is unreadable in comments, post it well-formatted as an edit (append) to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the wisdom. Unfortunately some of the CSV's date columns are blank; I adjusted my code and delimited by pipes. Tried to append to a list but am receiving the error.... " ValueError: time data '    ' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'"  CODE is in latest update above.