# Data truncuated for a column error with PHP and mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, truncate

I have written the following code on PHP and i am getting the error:
Data truncated for column 'datetime_gmt' at row 1;

Here is the code:

```
$lines = new SplFileObject('/home/file.txt');
$x = 0;
while(!$lines->eof()) {
    $lines->next();
    if($x == 0){
        $lines->next();
    }
    $row = explode(',',$lines);
    for($i = 0; $i<4; $i++){
        if(!isset($row[$i])){
            $row[$i] = null;
        }
    }
    $y = (float) $row[1];
    $z = (float) $row[2];
    $load_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO new (datetime_gmt,field2,field3)
    VALUES ('".$row[0]."','".$y."','".$z."');";
    $x++;
}
$lines = null;
```

The column is of type 'datetime' and has '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as DEFAULT, and it is the PRI of the table. If you are wondering about the "x" variable, it's for skipping the first 2 lines.

**EDIT 1**

Here is a sample data:

```
2013-12-11 8:22:00, 1.462E+12, 3.33E+11 
2013-12-12 4:10:00, 1.462E+12, 3.33E+11 
2013-12-13 11:52:00, 1.462E+12, 3.33E+11
```

And here is the description of the table "new":

```
Field         | Type      | Null  | Key  | Default            | Extra
datetime_gmt  | datetime  |No     | PRI  |0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
field2        | bigint(20)|YES    |      |NULL                |
field3        | bigint(20)|YES    |      |NULL                |
```

using:

```
SELECT sum(char_length(COLUMN_NAME)) 
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

I get 19 as the size of the column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data truncated for column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089240/data-truncated-for-column)

Comment: But the answer on that one says to change the column type to varchar. Can't i keep it Datetime?

Comment: `if($x = 0)` you're assigning here, rather than comparing `==` / `===` and will always be considered as being `0`.

Comment: What is the value of the first row that you are trying to insert? Can you post the data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305092/mysql-date-warning-data-truncated

Comment: the first row is as follows:

2013-12-11 8:22:00, 1.462E+12, 3.33E+11

Comment: A example of your data in file.txt could be helpfull

Comment: @mkaatman my data are in the correct format unlike the person on the link you posted. Thanks for helping though :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oops. Thanks for that. I changed it but i guess it won't fix the issue still. :(

Comment: welcome, but as suggested; to update your question with the data in that file and the db schema and their column length

Comment: Question has been updated.

Comment: Did you have to change your sql mode to allow this default 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for datetime?

Comment: i'm sorry, i dont quite understand you question?

Comment: Abdallah, run this query directly on your database: INSERT IGNORE INTO new (datetime_gmt,field2,field3) VALUES ('2013-12-11 8:22:00','1462000000000','333000000000'); Does that add a row on your database? If the answer is no, then remove your default value of 0000-00-00 00:00:00 then try again.

Comment: Yes i have tried to do so, and i still get the same error.

Comment: Now remove the default value: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and re-try

Comment: @RaviGehlot Sorry, that answer was before you edited your previous comment. I have tried to run the query you suggested and it worked fine. It even added a "0" in-front of the "8".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run this query directly into your database: INSERT IGNORE INTO new (datetime_gmt,field2,field3) VALUES ('2013-12-11 8:22:00','1462000000000','333000000000');

If that does not add a row, remove the default on the datetime_gmt column and re-try.

Note: You have a syntax error with your code.

Change this:

```
$load_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO new (datetime_gmt,field2,field3)
    VALUES ('".$row[0]"','".$y."','".$z."');";
```

To this:

```
$load_query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO new (datetime_gmt,field2,field3)
    VALUES ('".$row[0]."','".$y."','".$z."');";
```

If the aforementioned doesn't work, try to have just engine substitution in your SQL Modes:

```
set @@sql_mode='no_engine_substitution';
```

Then make sure that it shows NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION by running the following:

```
select @@sql_mode;
```

Then attempt to run your code again. The set @@sql_mode might not be server wide and it may only work for your current session.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but it acually does add a row. it even adds a "0" in-front of the "8".

Comment: Does it insert a row when the default of 0000-00-00 00:00:00 is set for the datetime_gmt column?

Comment: Yes it does. as for the error, it is correct in the code just not when i typed it here. sorry for that.

Comment: OK. Did you try to run your PHP script without the default set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 like I mentioned it in my answer? Please give that a go.

Comment: Are you running MySQL 5.7? If not, what version are you running? One other issue I can think of is that your code is forcing a blank insert into the database. So for example, if your file has a blank date, that could cause the error you are getting. Please review your plain text file.

Comment: It's MariaDB 5.6.19

Comment: Does every row in file.txt have a date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145743/discussion-between-ravi-gehlot-and-abdallah-qaraeen).

Comment: @Abdallah Hello, I wonder if my answer helped you at all? If so, please don't hesitate to mark it as your best answer.

Comment: Oops, sorry i was writing comments in the discussion chat.

Comment: If you go to the [discussion link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145743/discussion-between-ravi-gehlot-and-abdallah-qaraeen), you will see my comments there. Thanks :)